# Parse.com with Core Data for a book application

Tags: xml, xcode, sqlite, core-data, parse-platform

I am making an iphone app which is a book with translations in more than 40 different languages. I have each of the translations in a separate SQL database. If I import all the translations in Core Data, the app size is going to exceed 150 MB.

The user does not need access to all the translations. He/she just needs the translation in their native language. So, i don't want to preload the app with all the translations.

I am thinking of storing the translations on parse.com and give the user option to download the file for the translation they need. But i think it will take a lot of time to import the translations to Core Data after downloading the file from parse.com. Each database contains more than 6000 lines of text.

What will be the best way to implement this ?

I also have all the translations available in xml file.

Answer (score 1):

From your data i am assuming each language will need approximately 4 MB of data (150/40). You can easily store that much on parse.com since their limit for files is 10MB. The initial download and import might take a few minutes but since this is a one-time operation it shouldn't cause any problems.

Comment: so if a user downloads one translation sql file should i use core data to import everything or should i that file it as a separate database ?

Comment: Since it's a one time operation it shouldn't be an issue. But if you want to move away from coredata you should read this: http://inessential.com/2010/02/26/on_switching_away_from_core_data